# Amount of spaces not configurable in eclipse mars

Tags: linux, eclipse

I do not want to use tabs for indentation. So I check the option "Indent using spaces" but I can't set the amount of spaces. The Plus and Minus buttons are not clickable and I can't edit the value by hand, which means typing in a number. Indenting only one space is far too little.

I remember some hack including editing the workspace configuration files but I can't find the correct file or page I once read it on.

I am using Linux Mint, Eclipse for PHP Developers 4.5.1.

[image: Preferences screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Eclipse bug [479274](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479274)

You can work around it by editing the `indentationSize` entry in the properties file `org.eclipse.wst.css.core.prefs` which is in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` folder.

Comment: thank you, that was what I was looking for. Let's hope that this bug will finally be fixed any time soon.